# How to increase Size of popOverView in iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I ma Using Following code to pop photo library in ipad..

```
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    videoPicker.delegate = self;
    videoPicker.sourceType = 
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];
    videoPicker.allowsEditing = YES;;
    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:videoPicker];
   [pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    [videoPicker release];
```

How to increase the size of popOverView in this?

Answer (score 0):

The `popoverContentSize` property controls the size of the popover content view.